# Deleting records using different tables from different databases

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Here is the code I use:

```
DELETE FROM db1.table1 
WHERE db1.table1.Timestamp = db2.table2.Timestamp;
```

Can't prepare the statement at all. It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE from db1.table1 WHERE 
db1.table1.Timestamp IN( SELECT Timestamp FROM db2.table2) ;
```

It will delete all matching records from `db1.table1` with `db2.table2`

Comment: because, you are not fetching those records, you are only stating column from db2.table2 there. and a column can not be a value.